# JQuery Unresponsive Slow

Tags: jquery

My JQuery Code:

```
var divs = $('.headerlogo, .headertext');
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    divs.stop().fadeOut("fast"); 
    $('.header').animate({height:'35px'}, 500);
    } 
else {
    divs.stop().fadeIn("fast");
    $('.header').animate({height:'350px'}, 500);
    }
});
});
```

Please find my full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jJyJv/

When you scroll down the header "shrinks" as expected but does not come back when you scroll up the back as I would have expected. Sometimes just a small part of the header comes back then a few seconds later it fades back in or sometimes the navbar is missing and after a few seconds comes back. It should be instant and smooth.

New to JQuery so unsure why this happening. Any pointers would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to carefully examine your logic - adding in elements will change your required scroll values. I've cleaned it up a little so you can examine but you'll have to play around with the values to get it right: http://jsfiddle.net/jJyJv/2/

```
var divs = $('.headerlogo, .headertext');
$(document).ready(function() {
    var animating = false;
    var $window = $(window);
    $window.scroll(function () {
        if (!animating) {
            var $header = $('.header');
            if ($header.hasClass('open') && $window.scrollTop() > 100) {
                animating = true;
                divs.stop().fadeOut("fast"); 
                $header.animate({height:'35px'}, 500, function() { animating = false; }).removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
            } else if ($header.hasClass('closed') && $window.scrollTop() < 400) {
                animating = true;
                divs.stop().fadeIn("fast");
                $header.animate({height:'350px'}, 500, function() { animating = false; }).removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

A better solution would be to use CSS3 transitions which you can read about at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 0):

The scroll handler executes whenever the window scrolls, which means that even for a small scrolling action your handler will execute many many times, hence the unresponsive/slow behavior of the browser. The strange behavior you are seeing is a result of many many animation actions piling up and then executing sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Your animations run for every scroll event, even if the elements already have the state that they should have. That will stack up a huve amount of animations, so you have to wait a long time until they catch up.

Use a varible to keep track of the current state, and only animate when you change the state:

```
var divs = $('.headerlogo, .headertext');
$(document).ready(function(){
  var open = true;
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (open && s > 100) {
        open = false;
        divs.stop().fadeOut("fast"); 
        $('.header').animate({height:'35px'}, 500);
        } 
    else if (!open && s <= 100) {
        open = true;
        divs.stop().fadeIn("fast");
        $('.header').animate({height:'350px'}, 500);
        }
   });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jJyJv/1/